# DIV background image being cut off when zoomed out in firefox

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV with height/width of 15px. 
It has a background image also with height/width of 15px.
The problem is the background image is being cut off a few pixels on right and bottom when zoomed out some levels in firefox. 
Here's a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/xSRDs/) and code below. Try viewing it in firefox.

```
 <div id="custom-checkbox"></div>

 #custom-checkbox 
 { 
     background: url('http://s16.postimg.org/5xacziapd/unchecked.png') no-repeat; 
     width: 15px;
     height: 15px; 
 }
```

Comment: You should not expect a browser to render anything perfectly if in zoom mode.

Comment: I second Linus. Look at what a mess it could turn into trying to detect zoom levels: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5078596/1363726

Comment: Also agree with Linus. The problem you are seeing is probably due to the way Firefox rounds pixels (sub pixels). http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can get it to display the rest is just firefoxes pixel rounding.

> ```
>     #custom-checkbox   
> {   
>     background: url('http://s16.postimg.org/5xacziapd/unchecked.png') no-repeat;   
>     width: 15px !important;  
>     height: 15px !important;  
>     display:table;  
> }
> ```

Hope this helps it's the best I could do.